# QGraphicsRectItem is inherited from QGraphicsObject,unable to setRect and setGeometry to same QRect size

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

QGraphicsRectItem is inherited from QGraphicsObject,unable to setRect and setGeometry to same QRect size,

I am having problem in setting Geomtry of QGraphicsObject, position and width and height with size of QGraphicsRectItem.

I need to inherite my QGraphicsRectItem from QGraphicsObject for specific reason,(later I need to add svg images)

my work flow is as below.

widget -> class *Outer* (parent is "widget") -> class *InnerItem* (parent is "Outer") -> TextItem (parent is "InnerItem")

1. *Outer* is Red colour rect
2. *InnerItem * is green colour rect

setRect size of "*Outer*" Rectangle is calculated using "childrenBoundingRect()"
for "*InnerItem*" class is innerItem.childboundaryRect() which should be TextItem pos,width,height

I need the Green Rectangle box, drawned around TextItem and the entire Green Rectangle Box (innerItem) should be QObject which is done using setGeomtry.

1. At present all side of green box when I click, event.pos() returns
   , <**main**.InnerItem object at 0x7f6123af6a68>, )
   (But drawing is not around TextBox)

This is b'cos *innerItem*.childrenBoundingRect() would also contain
QGraphicsRectitem size of InnerItem, this is can be overcome by re-calculationg manually the childrenBoundingRect()

I have tried many option, but I am unable to set the QRectItem and QObject Rectangle size to be of same size and if I set then event.pos() doesn't return  <**main**.InnerItem object at 0x7f6123af6a68> it returns just
,  
on one of the size of RectItem

What I am doing wrong in setting the QGraphicsRectItem (setRect) and QGraphicsObject (setGeomtry)?

At-least logically what I am trying is correct or not.

I need some thing like First image and Second image is what I am getting:

[image]

```
class GraphicalView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self,parent)
        self.setScene(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event): 
        self.clickPosition  = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        print "---------- Start ----------"
        print self.items(event.pos())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        pass

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        self.clickPosition  = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        print "MRE ",self.items(event.pos())
        return

class QGObj(QtGui.QGraphicsWidget):
    """Base class for display elemenets in kinetics layout"""
    defaultFontName = "Helvetica"
    defaultFontSize = 10
    name = "ITEM"
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGraphicsObject.__init__(self,parent)
        self.gobj = None
        self.pressed = False
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable,True)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def getParentGraphicsObject(self):
        return self.parentItem()

    def paint(self, painter=None, option=None, widget = None):
        # painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5,Qt.Qt.DashLine, Qt.Qt.RoundCap, Qt.Qt.RoundJoin)))
        # print " painter in QGrapobj ",self.boundingRect(),self.pos(),self.gobj.boundingRect()
        # painter.drawRect(self.pos().x(),self.pos().y(),self.boundingRect().width(),self.boundingRect().height()) 
        if self.hasFocus() or self.isSelected():
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1,Qt.Qt.SolidLine, Qt.Qt.RoundCap, Qt.Qt.RoundJoin)))
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())        

    def itemChange(self,change,value):
        if change == QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemSelectedChange and value == True:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("qgtextItemSelectedChange(PyQt_PyObject)"),self.mobj)
        return QtGui.QGraphicsItem.itemChange(self,change,value)


class InnerItem(QGObj):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        QGObj.__init__(self,parent)
        self.gobj = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(self)


    def boundingRect(self):
        ''' reimplimenting boundingRect for redrawning '''

        return QtCore.QRectF(self.gobj.boundingRect())
        #return QtCore.QRectF(0,0,self.gobj.boundingRect().width(),self.gobj.boundingRect().height())

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        ## setting up the scene
        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view = GraphicalView(self.scene)
        #self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500)

        ## setting up MyRect
        outer = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem()
        outer.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.QColor("red"), 5, Qt.Qt.SolidLine, Qt.Qt.RoundCap, Qt.Qt.RoundJoin))

        ##inner RectItem, 
        ###child of Outer RectItem
        inner = InnerItem(outer)

        #textItem which is child of InnerItem class
        textItem  = QtGui.QGraphicsTextItem('My Text Here', inner)
        textItem.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.QColor("blue"))
        textItem.setPos(70,70)


        inner.gobj.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.QColor("green"), 5, Qt.Qt.SolidLine, Qt.Qt.RoundCap, Qt.Qt.RoundJoin))
        innerCBR = inner.childrenBoundingRect()
        #inner.gobj.setRect(0,0,innerCBR.width(),innerCBR.height())
        # print " innerCBR ",innerCBR
        # print inner.childItems()
        # x,y = [],[]
        # for i in inner.childItems():
        #     if not isinstance(i,QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):
        #         x.append((i.pos().x())+(i.boundingRect().bottomRight().x()))
        #         x.append(i.pos().x())
        #         y.append(i.pos().y()+i.boundingRect().bottomRight().y())
        #         y.append(i.pos().y())
        # innerCBR = QtCore.QRectF(min(x),min(y),max(x)-min(x),max(y)-min(y))

        inner.gobj.setRect(0,0,innerCBR.width(),innerCBR.height())

        inner.setGeometry(innerCBR.x(),innerCBR.y(),innerCBR.width(),innerCBR.height())

        outerCBR = inner.childrenBoundingRect()
        outer.setRect(outerCBR.x()-10,outerCBR.y()-10,outerCBR.width()+20,outerCBR.height()+20)
        self.scene.addItem(outer)


        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(layout) 

        self.setWindowTitle("QObj")
        #self.view.fitInView(self.scene.itemsBoundingRect().x()-10,self.scene.itemsBoundingRect().y()-10,self.scene.itemsBoundingRect().width()+20,self.scene.itemsBoundingRect().height()+20,Qt.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)
        self.view.show()
def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

[First image, this is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b87LM.png)

Comment: First image is not added, it would be just Green box should be around TextItem

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44850944/edit) your question and add the missing images please.